# Spring static resource servlet request

Tags: spring, servlets

My English is not good. Please understand it.

I'm in charge of maintaining a website built with Spring, tiles and ibatis frameworks.

The problem is all gif, js, etc... go through **DispatcherServlet** because most of the address of static resources are like **/home/images/hbg_01.gif**. the resource path is  mapped by **homeServlet**.

But I'd like my static resource to be ignored by any Dispatcher servlet written in Web.xml.

I am new to J2EE. so if it's lack of information. please leave comment. I will give you anything if needed

here's my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/xml/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/xml/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/xml/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>adminServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/xml/adminServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>adminServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>homeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/xml/homeServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>homeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>monitorServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/xml/monitorServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>monitorServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/monitor/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>monitorDemoServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/xml/monitorDemoServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>monitorDemoServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/monitor_demo/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>projectServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/xml/projectServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>projectServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/project/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <filter>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>encodingFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>EUC-KR</param-value>
        </init-param>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
       </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/home/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/project/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/monitor/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/monitor_demo/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>180</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mvc-static-resources can be of help. Pl. refer :

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

As you told  `/home/images/hbg_01.gif`. The resource path is mapped by `homeServlet`.

change url pattern `/home/*` to avoid mapped to `homeServlet` like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>homeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home/anything/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```